# Ionic start command from batch file

Tags: batch-file, ionic-framework, cmd

I want to create an application in ionic from a batch file, executing commands from a file named `appgenerator.bat`.

I have created the batch file but commands aren't recognized.

It works correctly when I enter the command at the Command Prompt, but not inside the file.

`appgenerator.bat`:

```bat
@echo %off

set nombreAPP=nuevaAPP2
set path=C:\Users\Antonio

ionic start %path%\%nombreAPP% blank
```

And this is the screen in cmd.exe (first I put "ionic" to probe that the command works and after "appgenerator" to start with my batch file)

[image]

I dont think that the problem is in system environment variables, because in the cmd window, work correctly.

Comment: Did you try running the batch with the complete path for the ionic executeable?

Comment: Do not set a variable to the name `path` and expect the default system variable `%PATH%` to still list all of the locations which contain paths to executables. Change the name, e.g. `Set "pth=C:\Users\Antonio"`.

Comment: It works!! I changed the variable name for "pth" and working perfect. Thank you!!